# React sort by value

Tags: reactjs, sorting, button

I have received a shell code which I need to add functionality to. I am quite the beginner with HTML, CSS, React and more that are imbedded in this shell. I have a json file with my tickets that include id, creation time, title etc. I wish to add a button to order the tickets by a value, the creation time for example. I have tried many formats that I have seen but none worked so far, this is the current state of the code **which returns: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortByDate' of undefined" regarding the toggleSortDate** (deleted the parts which I thought were irrelevant):

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import {createApiClient, Ticket} from './api';

export type AppState = {
    tickets?: Ticket[],
    search: string;
}

export class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, AppState> {

    state: AppState = {
        search: ''
    }

    sortByDate () {
        const {tickets} = this.state;
        let ordTickets = tickets
        ordTickets = tickets.sort((a, b) => a.creationTime < b.creationTime)
        this.setState({
            tickets: ordTickets
        })
    }

    toggleSortDate (event) {
    this.sortByDate()
    }

    renderTickets = (tickets: Ticket[]) => {

        const filteredTickets = tickets
            .filter((t) => (t.title.toLowerCase() + t.content.toLowerCase()).includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase()));
        return (<ul className='tickets'>
            {filteredTickets.map((ticket) => (<li key={ticket.title} className='ticket'>
                <h5 className='title'>{ticket.title}</h5>
                <button onClick={this.rename}>Rename</button>
                <h6 className='meta-data'> {ticket.content}</h6>
                <footer>
                    <div className='meta-data'>By {ticket.userEmail} | { new Date(ticket.creationTime).toLocaleString()}</div>
                </footer>
            </li>))}
        </ul>);
    }


    render() {
        const {tickets} = this.state;
        return (<main>
            <button onClick={this.darkMode}>Dark mode</button>
            <h1>Tickets List</h1>
            <header>
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." onChange={(e) => this.onSearch(e.target.value)}/>
            </header>
            <button onClick={this.toggleSortDate}>Sort by date</button>
            <button onClick={()=>this.onSort('date')}>Sort By Title</button>
            <button onClick={()=>this.onSort('date')}>Sort By Email</button>
            {tickets ? <div className='results'>Showing {tickets.length} results</div> : null }
            {tickets ? this.renderTickets(tickets) : <h2>Loading..</h2>}

        </main>)
    }
}
export default App;
    /*    <button onclick={this.sort(creationTime)}>Sort by date</button>*/
```

I would highly appreciate some help :)

***EDIT***

Thank you very much for your help, I have added the constructor as #k-wasilewski suggested, and I updated the sorting to this and it works:

```
sortByDate () {
        const {tickets} = this.state
        const arr = [...tickets].sort((a, b) => (a.creationTime < b.creationTime)? 1:-1)
console.log(tickets)
        this.setState({
            tickets : arr
        })
    console.log(arr);
    }
    SortDate (event) {
    this.sortByDate()
    }
```

Comment: Cause of the class component you are using I think you need to use bind `this.toggleSortDate.bind(this)` or wrap it in a function `{()=>this.toggleSortDate()}`

Answer (score 1):

To make global `this` identifiable have to bind your function within the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.toggleSortDate = this.toggleSortDate.bind(this);
}
```

or just use an arrow function, they are bound by default:

```
const toggleSortDate = (event) => {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed binding the your handler functions to the component instance, so `this` as in `this.sortByDate()` was `undefined` as the error message stated.

At the first line inside your class component, add the following:

```
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.toggleSort = this.toggleSort.bind(this);
  }
```

What this does is to let your handler functions have access to the component attributes. So if you need access to `this.props` or `this.state` inside a handler function, this binding will also be required.

References: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance